# Can't cast SQLINTEGER* to SQLLEN* (x64)

Tags: c++, odbc, stack, corruption

I'm calling SQLGetData() to get a field value. This works fine as a 32-bit application, but it's trashing the stack as 64-bit.

The strange thing is that SQLLEN is #defined as SQLINTEGER, so they are one and the same. They are both long types, as it turns out.

```
unsigned long Field::asUnsignedLong() const
{
unsigned long result;
SQLINTEGER sizeNeeded = 0;

    // Trashes the stack around sizeNeeded...
    if(!SQL_SUCCEEDED(SQLGetData(_statement, _columnIndex, SQL_C_ULONG, &result, sizeof(result), &sizeNeeded)))
    {
        throw std::runtime_error(getError(SQL_HANDLE_STMT, _statement));
    }

    return result;
}
```

Why does Visual Studio think it can't convert SQLLEN* to SQLINTEGER*? And when I force it using an explicit cast, why does the stack get corrupted?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `typedef` has [changed](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/298678) on the 64-bit API. Here's what's causing your stack corruption:

```
#ifdef _WIN64
typedef INT64 SQLLEN;
typedef UINT64 SQLULEN;
#else
#define SQLLEN SQLINTEGER
#define SQLULEN SQLUINTEGER
#endif
```

You're passing in a 32-bit integer (`SQLINTEGER` is `typedef`'d to `long`) when it is expecting a 64-bit one.

Comment: How does one fix this? simply use a SQLLEN?